# How to convert nested json to csv or excel?

Tags: python, json, csv

I am trying to come up with a general function in python to convert data in links like this https://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/api/json/title/2434.json to csv or Excel form.

An excerpt of the json:

```
{"Level1":
    [{"month":"1960-01","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"4981"},
     {"month":"1960-01","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2621"},
     {"month":"1960-01","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2360"},
     {"month":"1960-02","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"4596"},
     {"month":"1960-02","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2430"},
     {"month":"1960-02","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2166"},
     {"month":"1960-03","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"4964"},
     {"month":"1960-03","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2568"},
     {"month":"1960-03","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2396"},
     {"month":"1960-04","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"4904"},
     {"month":"1960-04","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2516"},
     {"month":"1960-04","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2388"},
     {"month":"1960-05","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5244"},
     {"month":"1960-05","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2658"},
     {"month":"1960-05","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2586"},
     {"month":"1960-06","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5178"},
     {"month":"1960-06","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2727"},
     {"month":"1960-06","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2451"},
     {"month":"1960-07","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5115"},
     {"month":"1960-07","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2568"},
     {"month":"1960-07","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2547"},
     {"month":"1960-08","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5331"},
     {"month":"1960-08","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2748"},
     {"month":"1960-08","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2583"},
     {"month":"1960-09","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5183"},
     {"month":"1960-09","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2705"},
     {"month":"1960-09","level_1":"Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2478"},
     {"month":"1960-10","level_1":"Total Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"5752"},
     {"month":"1960-10","level_1":"Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group","value":"2998"},'
```

I tried using pandas,

```
response = requests.get('https://www.tablebuilder.singstat.gov.sg/publicfacing/api/json/title/2434.json')

df = pandas.DataFrame(response)
df.to_csv('results.csv')
```

but it didn't work.

This is what I get when i use pandas: [image: pandas result]

but I'm trying to get something like this [image: wanted result]

Comment: Note that the "something like this" table is not really CSV standard. In CSV, each line should be independent of the other lines, whereas in the tables lines will depend on the lines before.

Comment: oh yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Have you tried `pd.DataFrame.from_records(jsons['Level1'])`?

Comment: At first, you may want to add `.json()` to your `requests.get()` object. Then, you may be able to work with this data.

Answer (score 1):

You can group the entries in the JSON by what they represent and collect the different months' values for those, then write them into a CSV file. Since lines in CSV should probably be independent of another, I suggest adding the "level 1" label with the "level 2" labels.

```
import json, collections
with open("2434.json") as f:
    d = json.load(f)
    by_type = collections.defaultdict(dict)
    for x in d["Level1"]:
        by_type[x["level_1"]][x["month"]] = x["value"]
    for x in d["Level2"]:
        by_type[x["level_1"] + " - " +  x["level_2"]][x["month"]] = x["value"]
    months = sorted(set(k for v in by_type.values() for k in v))

import csv
with open("2343.csv", "w") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    header = ["Month"] + months
    writer.writerow(header)
    for t in by_type:
        row = [t] + [by_type[t].get(k, -1) for k in months]
        writer.writerow(row)
```

A small excerpt from the resulting CSV:

```
Month,1960-01,1960-02,1960-03,1960-04,...
Total Live-births By Ethnic Group,4981,4596,4964,4904,5244,...
Total Male Live-births By Ethnic Group,2621,2430,2568,2516,2658,...
Total Female Live-births By Ethnic Group,2360,2166,2396,2388,2586,...
Total Live-births By Ethnic Group - Malays,838,836,849,843,872,...
Total Live-births By Ethnic Group - Chinese,3589,3290,3639,3610,3868,...
```